# Error using OpenJPA, persisting a many to many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, persistent

I'm working on a Java project and i have this problem for a few days now:

I'm using OpenJPA and i try to persist a many to many relationship with a extra column. I have a Employee who can have multiple skills. Skills can be rated by a level. So i have a EmployeeSkill class with the id's from employee and skill and a level.

When i try to persist skills to an employee a get this error. I tried all cascading actions and nothing is working and i dont know what to do anymore. :

```
openjpa-3.1.0-rafcec21a1d489dff682a3ce7986fac6a1c80e8e0 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The given instance "mijnsrc.app.entity.Employee-1" is not managed by this context.
FailedObject: mijnsrc.app.entity.Employee-1
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.getStateManagerImpl(BrokerImpl.java:4817)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persistInternal(BrokerImpl.java:2719)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2707)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2690)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.persist(BrokerImpl.java:2592)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.persist(DelegatingBroker.java:1197)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:837)
    at mijnsrc.app.persistence.Dao.insert(Dao.java:30)
    at mijnsrc.app.controller.EmployeeSkillController.setSkillToEmployee(EmployeeSkillController.java:33)
    at mijnsrc.app.service.EmployeeSkillService.setSkillToEmployee(EmployeeSkillService.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.PojoInvoker.performInvocation(PojoInvoker.java:43)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:258)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Employee entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private int employeeId;
    @Column(
            name = "first_name",
            nullable = false
    )
    private String firstname;
    @Column(
            name = "last_name",
            nullable = false
    )
    private String lastname;
    @Column(
            name = "email",
            nullable = false
    )
    private String email;
    @Column(
            name = "phone",
            nullable = false
    )
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private int isActive;
    @Column(name = "made_inactive_on")
    private String madeInactiveOn;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<EmployeeSkill> skills;
    @Transient
    @ManyToOne
    private Education education;

    public Employee() {

    }

    public Employee(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String phone, Education education) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.education = education;
        this.isActive = 1;
    }

    public Employee(int id, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String phone, Education education) {
        this.employeeId = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.education = education;
    }

    public void addSkill(Skill skill, int level) {
        EmployeeSkill employeeSkill = new EmployeeSkill(this, skill, level);
        skills.add(employeeSkill);
```

Skill entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skill")
public class Skill implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "skill_id")
    private int skillId;
    @Column(name = "skill_name", unique=true)
    private String skillName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "skill", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<EmployeeSkill> employees;
```

EmployeeSkill

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_skill")
public class EmployeeSkill {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeSkillKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("skill_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id")
    private Skill skill;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("employee_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    private int level;

    public EmployeeSkill() {

    }
```

EmployeeSkillKey

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeSkillKey implements Serializable {


    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private int employeeId;

    @Column(name = "skill_id")
    private int skillId;

    public EmployeeSkillKey() {

    }
```

Insert function

```
    /**
     * @param instance -> Instance of a entity
     */
    public void insert(T instance) throws Exception {
        try {
            emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(UNITNAME);
            entityManager = emFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.persist(instance);
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.close();
            emFactory.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

Controller calling the function

```
    private Dao<Employee> employeeDao;
    private Dao<Skill> skillDao;

    public void setSkillToEmployee(EmployeeSkillDTO dto) throws Exception {
        try {
            Employee employee = new Employee();
            employee.setId(dto.getEmployeeId());
            for (int[] s : dto.getSkills()) {
                Skill skill = skillDao.findById(s[0]);
                employee.addSkill(skill, s[1]);
            }
            employeeDao.insert(employee);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
      }
}
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Could you please add the EmployeeSkill mapping and how you are persisting the entities?

Comment: @PauloAraújo Oh i forgot, i've edited!

Comment: Still missing the insertion order. It may be your core problema.